# Itunes backup and restore for iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, backup, itunes, restore

I have an iPad app which stores some images inside Library directory of app.

If I backup my iPad with iTunes and restore the iPad from backup, I can see the images in the previously saved location but My app does not show those images If I try to read the images from same path.

Any idea why is this happening?

I can not store the images in Documents directory as iCloud will back it up and I don't want this images to be backed up by iCloud.

Thanks

Comment: Show how you obtain the path for the Library directory.

Comment: Btw:  you can tell iCloud not to backup your files: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses.
I was installing the app using the xcode and not iTunes which was causing the issue.

I created adhoc build and installed using he iTunes and everything worked fine.

Thanks